# Is my Mac Mini HDD about to fail?

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini

I carried my Mac Mini while traveling a few times, once to a different country and couple of times to different cities.

I once noticed the hard disk inside makes noise like its about to fail. But the noise is not noticeable unless the room is very very quiet, or when I keep my ear on the Mac Mini hardware and I can clearly hear the creeking noise from HDD.

But running disk verify shows no error. Will the apple store replace it for me due to bad health of the HDD? I am still under warranty.

Comment: Sounds just like it's working. It's no SSD ;)
-- besides you should be aware of the fact a Mac Mini is not a Macbook (traveling)

Comment: Haha yeah, but there are other threads here where people say it should be fine to carry it around

Comment: Keep an active backup and make sure you have AppleCare on that guy. A hard drive will fail (I guarantee it) simply because it is an out dated technology, if you don't like that thought go to an AASP that offers SSD upgrades and you'll be far, far happier

Comment: @AndrewU. Hard dirves don't fail because they heard from their buddy on the product aisle that they're not as cool as solid state drives. They fail because their mechanical moving parts wear out in anywhere from 3-10 years depending on the kind of drive that was bought (assume the shorter timeframe if it was just included in your purchase).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest taking a backup and going to an Apple Store soon.

I had two situations like this with funny creeking noises, the hard drive eventually slowed down and stopped working - no bad sectors or anything. It just eventually stopped.

It was not an Apple drive, but I am sure it's worth asking. Worst case scenario you will have to come back when drive eventually dies.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny clicking noise is normal for HDD since it is a mechanical head moving up and down during read and write process.

The Disk verify is not 100% checking every single sector.

To see if there are problems Open your console and type Error in the search window and look for Disk I/O errors.

If you have them, those are the first signs of disk failure.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to think of is that sometimes a noisy/failing HD noise is sometimes actually fan noise.

Especially if you have been carrying it around. Fans tend to be much more fragile than hard drives and fans in computers NOT designed to be carried around may experience bumps that could eventually damage them.

If it is possible to run the Mini with is partially disassembled (basically out of the case) you might be able to be sure where the noise is coming from.